# Converting ggplot to plotly - one line in different colors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I want to have plot where one line in drawn in different colors as in example below:

```
test_data <-
    data.frame(
        var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
        var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
        date = seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100)
    )

plot <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = date)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = var0, group = 1, colour = c(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 25), rep("a", 50)))) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1"))
plot
```

[image]

I what to have the same plot in plotly or some other interactive library in R (so that the lables with some data could be displayed when moving the mouse on some specific line/point). When I use `ggplotly` I get something like this

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

Do you know how to combine red and green line in one line (in ggplot it is done through `group=1` parameter)?

Comment: Why `colour=c(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 25), rep("a", 50)))` ?

Comment: It's just an example, I want to have one line in two different colors and this line makes values between 26 and 50 green (group b) and all the other red (group a). The main point of this question is how to make `plotly` think that this sequence should be still one line, not two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises as there's no data for "a" for lines 26:50 (around 2004 and 2005) with the group assignment. The line jump when ggplot force join points from line 25 and line 51, which appear in ggplotly.

Here's my attempt with a long form of data:

```
t2 <- test_data[26:50, ]
t2$gp <- "b"
test_data$gp <- "a"

df <- rbind(test_data, t2)
df <- gather(df, var, value, -date,  - gp)

plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df %>% filter(var=="var0"), aes(x=date, y=value, colour=gp)) +
  geom_line(data=df %>% filter(var=="var1"), aes(x=date, y=value, colour=var))
```

[image]

```
ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]