# Individual curves according to class. From ggplot to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I would like to trace individual curves with a color modification during the time according to a class. I've found how to do it with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

id <- c(rep(1,12), rep(2,12))
age <- c(0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 13, 27, 41, 55, 60, 69, 83)
age2 <- age+1
age3 <- c(age, age2)
value <- c(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.05, 0.05, 0.20, 0.20, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
value2 <- value+0.05
value3 <- c(value, value2)
statut <- c("+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-")
statut2 <- c("-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-")
statut3 <- c(statut, statut2)

df <- cbind.data.frame(id, age3, value3, statut3)

p <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = age3, y = value3, color = statut3, group = id)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("steelblue", "tomato1"))
p
```

Result:
[image: Plot with ggplot]
.

Unfortunately, when I use ggplotly, I can't get the same graph:

```
p2 <- ggplotly(p)
p2
```

Result:
[image: Plot with ggplotly]

What should I do please?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you convert  statut3 to numbers before the 2 plots??? `df$statut3 <- ifelse(statut3=="+",1,0)`

Comment: I'm not able to do it. I've got this message after ggplot sentence: "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale".

Comment: have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409858/converting-ggplot-to-plotly-one-line-in-different-colors?

Comment: I haven't seen it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the exact answer but thanks to MLavoie I could find something close:

```
test <- df[which(df$statut3 == "+"),]
test$statut3 <- "-"
df2 <- rbind(df, test)

p <- ggplot(df2) + 
geom_line(aes(x = age3, y = value3, color = statut3, group = id)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("steelblue", "tomato1"))
p

p2 <- ggplotly(p)
p2
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPzT6.png)